# How to create a user and save it the DB in rails using backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, ruby-on-rails-3.2

How to create a model/user and save it the DB in rails using backbone.js

Comment: Your question is too broad. Backbone prefers to work with RESTful services so you write a simple RESTful CRUD system in Rails and Backbone talks to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**[Backbone]**

Define a User model:

```
var User = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults:{
        birthday: "Unknown"
    },
    url: "/users",    //create user RESTful service url
    validate: function(attrs,options){
        if(attrs.name===''){    //simple checking
            return "name can't be blank";
        }
    }
});

//define save callback
function onSuccess(model, response, options){
    console.log(response);
}

function onError(model, xhr, options){
    console.log("error");
}

//create user instance
var user = new User();

//validation
user.on("invalid",function(model,error){
    alert(error);
});
//save data to backend
user.save({name:"Jimmy",age:"12",gender:"male"},{success:onSuccess,error:onError});
```

By default, backbone using jquery.ajax to make a RESTful JSON request. If you want to use other method, you have to override Backbone.sync.

Hope this is helpful  for you.